# Aligning text cells in a TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

How can I align text content in a two-column TableLayout so that the text in the left column in aligned to the right and the text in the left column is aligned to the left, making them "fastened" to each other around the middle of the screen?

It should look something like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|           Title: | Value          |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a small example that provides what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <TextView
            android:text="left at right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="right at left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `TextView`

Use the attributes

```
<TextView
  ....
  android:gravity="center|right"` 
/>
```

,

```
<TextView
  ....
  android:gravity="center|left"
/>
```

in the xml layout

or

`textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER);` and `textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER);` in java

Comment: Thanks @Gautam.  Can you please provide a short XML so I'll know for sure which elements you refer to?

Comment: Its obvious that I am referring to `TextViews`

Comment: @Guatam, please trust me that nothing is obvious on your very first axml... :)